# "Not one for" something (e.g., social pleasantries)

Tags: meaning

> **Not one for social pleasantries**, the chief of staff would brusquely ask his subordinates anything he wanted, even coffee.

What does it mean?

Comment: You should include the research you have done in your question.

Comment: I found nothing!

Comment: @JeremyC "not one for" indeed consists of words that are too general to find something from established sources while googling. There _is_ [a wordreference question](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/be-not-one-for.3010543/), though. So, Mo-stafa, you should really learn the trick of googling for phrases while putting them in quotation marks: ["not one for"](https://www.google.com/search?q="not+one+for"&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) (with quotation marks). Read [the help](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to understand how this forum works. And welcome to ELL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Not one for** something" means "he is not *the type of person* who is inclined to something."

In this particular case, this guy is probably very direct, even brusque; he doesn't care about manners (social pleasantries).

Someone can be

> not one for complaining

(He doesn't like to complain)

> not one for sentiments

(He doesn't like to be emotional or nostalgic about something)

> not one for words

(He doesn't like to talk a lot, or might sometimes struggle expressing what he feels.)

Comment: Note that this is because **for** can have the meaning "in favor of."  For example, "I'm for it!" means "I want to do it [whatever is being discussed]!"  So **"not...for"** means "not in favor of. "

Comment: @CanadianYankee I'm not feeling the presence of "in favor of". Rather, there is an ineffable smell of "falling for something" in the background.

Comment: Honestly, I can tell this is the most helpful site ever, thanks a lot)